# Use the energy method to prove the uniqueness of the initial boundary value problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm having trouble of proving the uniqueness of the initial boundary value problem

$$u_t-ku_{xx}\ =0,  \ 0<x<l, \ 0<t<T$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x),  \ 0<x<l$$ 
$$u_x(0,t)=0, \ u(l,t)=h(t),\ 0<t<T$$

This is what I have so far:

Let $w(x, t)=u_1(x,t)-u_2(x,t)$, where $u_1(x,t) $ and $u_2(x,t)$ are two solutions of the problem, and hence so is $w(x,t)=0$, so the goal is to prove $w(x,t)=0$

Let energy integral $E(t)=\int_0^lw^2 \ dx$

Then $d/dt(E)=\int_0^l2ww_t\ dx$

Integral by parts we have $E'(t)=2k(w(l,t)w_x(l,t)-w(0,t)w_x(0,t))-2k\int_0^lw_x^2 \ dx$

Then $E'(t)=2kh(t)w_x(l,t)-2k\int_0^lw_x^2 \ dx$

Since $ u(l,t)=h(t)$

Then $u_x(l,t)=h_x(t)=0$, so $w_x(l,t)=0$

Thus $E'(t)=-2k\int_0^lw_x^2 \ dx$

Not so sure how to continue here. Supposedly $E'(t)<0$ suggests that $E(t)$ is non increasing, and then $E(0)=f(x)$

How do we conclude $E=\int_0^lw^2 \ dx =0$?

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Hint: $ \frac{dE}{dt} = \frac{d^{2}u(x,t)}{dxdt} $ which is adequate if the P.D.E is 1st order. So solving for $ E'(t) = 0 $ should provide a complete initial value.

[We could help more if we saw the P.D.E concerned with the initial value equation above]

Comment: You'll pretty much want to follow what is done [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sew6XBd2rRY).

Comment: Your integration by parts is false. Note that $E$ is a function of $t$ alone, so you don't compute $dE/dx$ but $dE/dt = \int_0^l 2 w(x, t) w_t(x, t) dx$. In this integral, replace $w_t$ in terms of $w_x$, then integrate by parts carefully. Don't write random statements: $E(0)$ is not a function of $x$, it is a number (which one?)

Comment: @Gribouillis Thank you, I fixed the integration, I'm thinking E(0) should be 0 but $E(0)=\int_0^lw^2(x,0)dx=\int_0^lf^2(x)dx$, which is >=0

Comment: $w(x, 0) = u_1(x,0)- u_2(x,0) = $? Also the [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) is still false.

Comment: @Gribouillis Oh! I see it now! Thank you! And there was a typo in the original equation, so $w_t=kw_{xx}$, not$kw_xx$, so after replacing $w_t$ with $w_{xx}$. it follows with $E'(t)=2kww_x|_0^l-2k\int_0^lw_x^2dx$ Thank you so much!